# Is it possible to execute ampscript or ssjs onchange via checkbox check/uncheck

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs, subscription-center

As I wrote in the question title I was just wondering if a block of ampscript & ssjs combined code can be execute on change via checkbox check/uncheck?

```
<input name="TopicID" type="checkbox" onchange="sub-unsub" value="Newsletter"
                                    %%[ IF @TopicID == "Koronavirus" THEN ]%% checked %%[ ENDIF ]%%>&nbsp;&nbsp;Novica1</label>
```

and I would like to call this code onChange()

```
%%[
SET @sub = "EmailAddress" 
SET @email = "EmailAddress"
SET @Listid = "ListID"
SET @ListStatus = "Active"
SET @listemailexist = Lookup("_ListSubscribers","EmailAddress","ListID", @Listid,"EmailAddress", @email,"Status", @ListStatus)
]%%

%%[if @listemailexist == @email AND @ListStatus == "Active" Then]%%
subscriber already exist
%%[ELSE]%%
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.5"); 
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'}]};

//getting values from AMPSCRIPT variables to SSJS variables
var email = Variable.GetValue("@email");
var subscriberkey = Variable.GetValue("@sub");

function AddToSub(obj) {
var props = { 
SubscriberKey: subscriberkey,
EmailAddress: email,
Lists: [{
ID: obj.listID,
Status: 'Active' // to unsub = "Unsubscribed" to subscribe = "Active"
}]
};
var data = prox.updateItem("Subscriber", props, options);
return data.Results[0].StatusCode;
}

var myPubLists = [
{mid:'MID', listID:'ListID'}
];

for (var i=0; i<myPubLists.length; i++) {
var result = AddToSub(myPubLists[i]);
Write("Subscriber has been added to the publication list");
}
</script>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Has anyone tried this before.

Tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't execute neither SSJS nor Ampscript clientside.

My best advice to you would be to create an [JSON Code Resource](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_code_resource.htm&type=5) in Cloud Pages, populating it with your code. This code is executed when the Code Resource URL is called, which should be done from your `onChange()` function. You will be able to populate the JSON response with e.g. status of code execution.

In order to overcome CORS limitations, you should utilise a JSONP approach: You essentially make a GET request with a callback parameter:

```
(get) http://cloudpages.example.com/endpoint?callback=foo
```

Ampscript/SSJS will wrap the JSON reply in a function call to your callback, where you can handle it:

```
foo({"your": "json", here: true})
```